# can't make z-index work on sub menu

Tags: wordpress, z-index

i have a sidebar menu on my WordPress widget area, and sub-menu items are displayed under main content, i can't make it work with z-index, where should i put CSS code to make it work

i tried adding z-index to my style codes, and nothing happened, maybe i put them in a wrong place or i have to use some sort of other code with style code

you can see the problem on the main page

website address is:  http://www.nanotajhiz.com

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have `overflow: hidden;` on your `.sidebar` which holds the items, which causes any content that goes outside the sidebar to be hidden.

You should remove `overflow: hidden` from `.sidebar` and adjust the other layout styles accordingly. You can use the clearfix method instead ( [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) ).